# Namespace Registries not showing up anywhere

Tags: namespace, app-launcher

I am an administrator and I cannot find this app anywhere to link a namespace in a developer org. Why does this seem so incredibly hard to do? All the examples that say create SalesforceDX permission reference Object Settings that do not exist. 
[Add SFDX Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm)

Comment: Do you have Dev Hub turned on, access to the object at the profile level, and My Domain active in the Dev Hub?

Comment: yes I actually am on Namespace Registries tab but there is no Link Namespace buttonFrom the App Launcher menu, select Namespace Registries.
Click Link Namespace.

Comment: Ahh I see everything and was able to link. I basically just created a new Dev Hub and then linked with existing namespace. All is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I basically just created a new Dev Hub and then linked with existing namespace